# Remove Everything Before A Certain Character Or Space?

Tags: notepad++

This is what I have.

```
Proxies #125: 179.185.66.146:3128
Proxies #126: 180.183.148.131:8081
Proxies #127: 180.183.179.178:8080
Proxies #128: 180.183.180.60:8080
Proxies #129: 180.234.206.77:8080
Proxies #130: 180.246.101.143:8080
Proxies #131: 180.250.252.3:8080
Proxies #132: 180.252.64.215:80
Proxies #133: 180.253.96.85:8080
```

It continues like that but the #123, #124, etc is not in order all the way.

I want it like this

```
179.185.66.146:3128
180.183.148.131:8081
180.183.179.178:8080
180.183.180.60:8080
180.234.206.77:8080
180.246.101.143:8080
180.250.252.3:8080
180.252.64.215:80
180.253.96.85:8080
```

Ho do I get it like that in Notepad++?

Comment: Use a regex replacement - `^Proxies\h#\d+:\h`.

Comment: How would I do that in NotePad++ ? I'm new to it.

Comment: `Ctrl+H` > **Find What**: `^Proxies\h#\d+:\h` -> Check *Regular expression* -> click *Replace All*.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl+H` to display the *Find and Replace* dialog.

Paste the regex into **Find What**: `^Proxies\h#\d+:\h`.

Then check the *Regular expression* radio button at the bottom.

Click *Replace All* button.

**Pattern Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `Proxies` - a substring
- `\h`  - 1 horizontal space
- `#` - a `#` symbol
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `:`  - a colon
- `\h` -  1 horizontal space.

[image]